# Bound mismatch with Java Generics "nesting"

Tags: java, generics

I'm having difficulty using generics for a redesign/refactoring I'm doing on an existing design.

```
public interface DataDto {
    // some data here
}

public interface SetDto<MyDataDto extends DataDto> {
    List<MyDataDto> getData();
}

public interface Results<MySetDto extends SetDto<DataDto>> {
    MySetDto getResults();
}

public interface MyProblemInterface<MyDataDto extends DataDto,
        MySetDto extends SetDto<MyDataDto>,
        MyResults extends Results<MySetDto>> {
    // some stuff here
}
```

My problem is that I get the following error for `MyProblemInterface`:

```
Bound mismatch: The type MySetDto is not a valid substitute for the
bounded parameter <MySetDto extends SetDto<DataDto>> of the type
Results<MySetDto>
```

I admit my experience with generics is somewhat limited, but basically I'm trying to enforce that all three of the types in `MyProblemInterface` are the same "type".  For example, if I have `ADataDto`, `BDataDto`, `ASetDto<ADataDto>`, `BSetDto<BDataDto>`, `AResults<ASetDto>`, `BResults<BSetDto>`, I want to ensure a class can't implement MyProblemInterface in a manner like `AMyProblemInterface<ADataDto, ASetDto, BResults>`.  I would think that since `MySetDto` extends `SetDto<MyDataDto>` just fine, I could continue to take that further, but I'm apparently wrong.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Try changing the Results declaration to `Results<MySetDto extends SetDto<? extends DataDto>>` - not sure I have the syntax right, but if you say SetDto<DataDto> then it expects to see exactly that generic signature.

Answer (score 0):

You want too much from Java generics.

It would be simpler to declare your interface as following:

```
public interface MyProblemInterface<MyDataDto extends DataDto>
```

And then force method to use `SetDto<MyDataDto>` and `Results<MySetDto>`.

By using generics in class/interface declaration you specify some kind of variety which is determined later in definition. But in your case you said that `SetDto` and `Results` will always have `MyDataDto` as parameter, so there is no variety.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be something like this instead, and you add the actual classes only when implementing the interfaces.

Updated the code, because I forgot to add the right Results definition. This should work.

```
public interface DataDto {
    // some data here
}

public interface SetDto<T extends DataDto> {
    List<T> getData();
}

public interface Results<T extends SetDto<? extends DataDto>> {
    T getResults();
}

public interface MyProblemInterface<T extends DataDto, E extends SetDto<T>, K extends Results<E>> {
    // some stuff here
}
```